# show first, second and third prize on one line

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have to use SQL sub-queries to answer the below questions.

the original table is
prize

```
event_id    place     money
101         1          120
101         2          60
101         3          30
102         1          10
102         2          5
102         3          2
103         1          100
103         2          60
103         3          40
401         1          1000
401         2          500
401         3          250
401         4          100
401         5          50
```

the question is: for each event, list the prize money available for first, second and third prize on one line. order by event_id. the first line of the table is like:
event_id        first         second        third
101             120            60            30
.....

My answer here is: 
USE horsedb;

```
SELECT event_id,
(SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place = '1' AND event_id = prize.event_id) AS 'First',
(SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place = '2' AND event_id = prize.event_id) AS 'Second',
(SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place = '3' AND event_id = prize.event_id) AS 'Third'
FROM prize
ORDER BY event_id;
```

but the answer has a 1024 ( return more than one rows) error. and I tried IN, ANY the results are no good.
please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
select event_id,
       max(first) as first,
       max(second) as second,
       max(third) as third
  from (select event_id,
               case when place = 1 then money else null end as first,
               case when place = 2 then money else null end as second,
               case when place = 3 then money else null end as third
          from prize
       )t
 group by event_id;
```

And sqlfiddle if you need it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa691/1/0

Answer (score 0):

The question not clear in terms of what the output should look like, but here is a suggestion:
Try using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT. Example:

```
SELECT event_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(place ORDER BY place) AS place,
       GROUP_CONCAT(money ORDER BY place) AS money
FROM prize
GROUP BY event_id;
```

gives:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| event_id | place     | money               |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|      101 | 1,2,3     | 120,60,30           |
|      102 | 1,2,3     | 10,5,2              |
|      103 | 1,2,3     | 100,60,40           |
|      401 | 1,2,3,4,5 | 1000,500,250,100,50 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
```